# using parameters in group by statment

Tags: sql-server

I just wanna do a simple query with grouping by "Age_Band".
And to set the parameter to help me change the grouping column easily.
But got an error:
"Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference. "

How did I make mistake on using the parameter? Thanks a lot

```
DECLARE @group nvarchar(50);  
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);  
SET @SQLString =  
    N'SELECT AVG(Loan_Amount) as Avg_Loan_Amount
 ,count(Loan_Amount)
 ,SUM(Loan_Amount) as Sum_Loan_Amount
 ,SQRT(SUM(Loan_Amount)) as Square_Loan_Amount
 ,Age_Band
 ,SUM(Interest_Paid_Amount) as Sum_Interest_Paid_Amount
 ,GETDATE()as today 
   FROM [dbo].[Loan]   
   group by @groupcol';  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@groupcol nvarchar(50)'; 
SET @group=N'Age_Band'
exec  sp_executesql  @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,  
                  @groupcol = @group;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use parameter in the `group by` clause by you can build query string using parameter. Something like this.

```
DECLARE @group nvarchar(50) = N'Age_Band'; --set col name
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);  
SET @SQLString =  
    N'SELECT AVG(Loan_Amount) as Avg_Loan_Amount
 ,count(Loan_Amount)
 ,SUM(Loan_Amount) as Sum_Loan_Amount
 ,SQRT(SUM(Loan_Amount)) as Square_Loan_Amount
 ,' + @group + ' 
 ,SUM(Interest_Paid_Amount) as Sum_Interest_Paid_Amount
 ,GETDATE()as today 
   FROM [dbo].[Loan]   
   group by ' + @group;  
exec  sp_executesql  @SQLString;
```

Comment: Yap, thank you very much. I revised my code and get it successfully run but no query result displayed. How can I get the result out? Thanks

Comment: Add `print @SQLString`. Try output as a query.